# Equivalent C code in C#. (uint8_t *) cast?

Tags: c#, c

I am trying to convert these C piece of code into C#. But I've stumble in some parts that I don't understand exactly what is happening, so I am unable to translate it.

```cpp
void foo(uint64_t *output, uint64_t *input, uint32_t Length){

    uint64_t st[25];

    memcpy(st, input, Length);

    ((uint8_t *)st)[Length] = 0x01;

    memset(((uint8_t *)st) + Length + 1, 0x00, 128 - Length - 1);

    for(int i = 16; i < 25; ++i) st[i] = 0x00UL;

    // Last bit of padding
    st[16] = 0x8000000000000000UL;

    bar(st);

    memcpy(output, st, 200);
}
```

More specifically in the `((uint8_t *)st)[Length] = 0x01;` part. I cannot understand the cast/pointer in this line. Why is the `*` there for? If somebody could explain what is happening, I would be grateful.

What I got so far in C#:

```cs
private void foo(ref ulong[] output, ref ulong[] input, uint Length)
    {
        ulong[] st = new ulong[25];

        //memcpy(st, input, Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(input, 0, st, 0, (int)Length);

        // Help in these line please:
        //((uint8_t *)st)[Length] = 0x01;

        // Still don't know what to do here too:
        //memset(((byte)st) + Length + 1, 0x00, 128 - Length - 1);

        for (int i = 16; i < 25; ++i)
        {
            st[i] = 0x00U;
        }

        // Last bit of padding
        st[16] = 0x8000000000000000U;

        bar(st);

        //memcpy(output, st, 200);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(st, 0, output, 0, 200);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is tagged `c++`.

Comment: Please remove the C++ tag. Can you also explain in words what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: c++ tag removed, sorry.

Comment: `uint8_t` is the closest you have to a `byte` type in C, for accessing raw memory as bytes. And even in C the code sucks big time. You should *really* figure out what `foo` is **supposed** to be doing and recode that in your language.

Comment: The purpose of `((uint8_t *)st)[Length] = 0x01;` appears to be write out of bounds of the array, in order to create a program crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your function does is rather primitive memory manipulation:

```
void foo(uint64_t *output, uint64_t *input, uint32_t Length)
{
  uint64_t st[25];
```

Your function takes a pointer to 16 elements of `uint64_t` and prepares a local buffer (`st`) to store a copy of them.

```
  memcpy(st, input, Length);
  ((uint8_t *)st)[Length] = 0x01;
  memset(((uint8_t *)st) + Length + 1, 0x00, 128 - Length - 1);
```

Make a copy of the `input` array into `st` but insert a byte with value 1 at an offset of `Length` bytes from the start.

```
  for(int i = 16; i < 25; ++i) st[i] = 0x00UL;
```

The remaining 8 elements of the buffer are cleared to 0. Writing `st[16]` is pointless as it will be changed again by the next line...

```
  // Last bit of padding
  st[16] = 0x8000000000000000UL;
```

Now we have 16*8 bytes from the input buffer, 1 extra byte with value 1 inserted somewhere and the remaining elements are filled with 1<<63 and lots of 0 bytes.

```
  bar(st);

  memcpy(output, st, 200);
}
```

Do something we have no clue about and copy the resulting 25 elements into the `output` buffer